# NameError: name 'ActivityType' is not defined

Tags: windows-10, discord.py

```
t = ctx.message.author.activity.name 

print('Имя:')
print(t)

activitys_type = str(ctx.author.activities[0].type)
print('Тип:')
print(activitys_type)
    if activitys_type is not None:
        if activitys_type is ActivityType.playing:
            idraw.text((40, 170), f'Играет в {t}', font = normaltext)
```

Этот код должен показывать мне Деятельность человека.
Мучаюсь около часа и не могу понять в чём проблема, помогите пожалуйста!
Также if ctx.author.activities[0].type == str('ActivityType.playing'): не выдаёт ошибку в консоль, но также и не выводит деятельность человека.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно преобразовывать `ctx.author.activities[0].type` в `str`. В строке `if activitys_type is ActivityType.playing:` вы сравниваете строку с классом, поэтому там будет априори `False`.

Так же и в `if ctx.author.activities[0].type == str('ActivityType.playing'):` будет всегда `False`, но здесь вы уже зачем-то преобразуете обращение к классу.свойство к строке, в этом состоянии оно не имеет никакого смысла, не говоря уже о том, что преобразуется фактически строка к строке :)

Пример команды:

```py
async def activity(ctx):
    activity_name = ctx.message.author.activity.name 
    activity_type = ctx.author.activities[0].type

    print(f'Имя:\n{activity_name}')
    print(f'Тип:\n{activity_type}')

    if activity_type is not None and activity_type == discord.ActivityType.playing:
        idraw.text((40, 170), f'Играет в {activity_name}', font=normaltext)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, команда работает, но если я ни чего не делаю и прописываю команду, то по идеи из строчки if activity_type is not None мне просто не должно в карточке писаться "Играет в ...", но он пишет мне AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name.

Comment: Так и должно быть. Можно исхитриться и решить это тернарным условием: `activity_type = ctx.message.author.activity.name if ctx.message.author.activity is not None else "Не во что не играет"`

Comment: Мне кажется ты опечатался в type и name, ведь мне выдавало ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' в строке activity_name = ctx.message.author.activity.name, а ты написал про type, да и почему activity_type = message.author.activity.name. Когда я вставил твоё тернарное условие вместо прошлого то мне написало ту же ошибку

Comment: Опечатался просто, но принцип должен быть понятен - если activity равняется None, то переменной должна присваивается нужная нам строка, иначе будет присвоено `activity.<attribute>`.

Comment: Так вот я изменил твою опечатку: activity_name = ctx.message.author.activity.name if ctx.message.author.activity is not None else "Не во что не играет" и мне выдаёт ошибку: в activity_type = ctx.author.activities[0].type ошибка IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#member

Answer (score 0):

Вот кому нужен готовый, без ошибок код для написания с помощью библиотеки PIL активности игрока:

```
activity_name = ctx.message.author.activity.name if ctx.message.author.activity is not None else "Не чего не делает"
if activity_name == "Не чего не делает":
    # print('Не во что не играет')
    pass

if activity_name != "Не чего не делает":
    # print('во что то играет!')
    activity_type = ctx.author.activities[0].type



activity_type2 = ctx.message.author.activity # если нету то None
    if activity_type2 is not None and activity_type == discord.ActivityType.playing:
        idraw.text((40, 170), f'Играет в {activity_name}', font=normaltext)
```